# Switch solc compiler versions

Tags: solidity, solc, installation, compiler

I have `solc` v0.5.2 on my system, but I have several contracts, that require `solc` < v0.5, so that I get errors:

> Error: Source file requires different compiler version

What is the best way to run and choose between multiple versions of `solc`?

Just download `solc` v0.4.25, rename it into e.g. `solc04` and move it into `/usr/bin/`? Or is there something like virtual environments for `solidity`?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the new truffle feature, the ability to specify your solidity compiler, https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0#user-content-what-s-new-in-truffle-v5-truffle-compile-solidity-specify-your-compiler-version.

As for manually switching between the 2, I think docker would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I found useful this solc version switcher tool https://github.com/crytic/solc-select.

My experience to configure it:

1. `docker pull trailofbits/solc-select`
2. manually add https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crytic/solc-select/master/bin/solc to any location
3. add permissions to execute the script to the owner `chmod u+x ...`
4. add location from 2. to .bash_profile

Now I am able to switch between Solidity versions with `solc use ...`